# pike.exception.StreamLostError python pika rabbitmq

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I get `pike.exception.StreamLostError: Stream connection lost: connectionResetError(10054...` when I call `connection.channel()`:

```
p = pika.ConnectionParameters('localhost')
c = pika.BlockingConnection(p)
channel = connection.channel()
...
```

RabbitMQ 3.11.16
Erlang 26.0

Comment: RAbbitMQ and Erlang Versions?

Comment: @GabrieleSantomaggio RabbitMQ 3.11.16 Erlang 26.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using Erlang 26 with RabbitMQ 3.11.x. Erlang 26  is incompatible with RabbitMQ 3.11.x

You have to use Erlang 25 for RAbbitMQ 3.11.x See https://www.rabbitmq.com/which-erlang.html

Erlang 26 is not officially supported yet; we are working on it;

Comment: Thank, I'll try it now. Another related question if I may - https://github.com/alanxz/SimpleAmqpClient/issues/102. I thought It's possible to use a different channel from each thread using the same connection, but from this issue I see it's not thread safe in this cpp library. So I should create a new connection for each thread?

Comment: Yes you need a connection per thread

Comment: I am undergoing the same issue with RabbitMQ 3.11.1 and Erlang 25.1.1, so I don't think that is the root cause